# How has $\tan(x)$ become more popular than $\operatorname{tg}(x)$?

Tags: mathematics, terminology, notation, russia

I know that some Eastern European and Middle Asian countries denote the tangent by $\operatorname{tg}$. For many years, I have used $\tan$ instead, but am currently thinking of changing that notation to $\operatorname{tg}$. I think $\operatorname{tg}$ is better than $\tan$ because I can write $\operatorname{tg}$ in cursive very easily (unlike $\tan$).

I would like to know why the United States, with its many Nobel prizes, has been using $\tan$ rather than $\operatorname{tg}$.

Comment: It is already addressed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179881/best-way-to-denote-some-trigonometric-functions-tg-vs-tan-ctg-vs-cot

Comment: Do you really think that the evolution of language (also symbolic one) is fully "rational"? Having said that, why "tan"? because it is the abbreviation of [tangent](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Miller/mathword/t/): from Latin *tangens*.

Comment: The $\tan$ abbreviation became commonplace in England since the 17th century ($\textrm{tang}$ and $\textrm{t}$ were also used). The $\textrm{tg}$ abbreviation was occasionally used by Euler, but did not gain much traction until the 19th century, and only on the Continent, see [Cajori, History of Mathematical Notation, v.II](https://archive.org/details/AHistoryOfMathematicalNotationVolII/page/n189/mode/2up?view=theater). The US simply followed English use, and textbooks eventually canonized it. If you are looking for "deep reasons" there are none, herding and inertia do the work.

Comment: @Conifold I like your "herding and inertia do the work"